# Why is there a big margin on the right?

Tags: html, css

I was experimenting with block-level elements. I opened my html file and started inspecting it after pressing Ctrl+Shift+J and on the right of the , there is a big margin (although I didn't set any.) Could you clarify why is it appearing?

```css
aside {
    padding: 0.4rem; 
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0.25rem;
}

.anchor {
    display: block;
    /*width: 30vw;*/
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(22, 122, 56);
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-part.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <aside>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/" class="anchor">Wiki</a>
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/" class="anchor">Impeach</a>
        </aside>
        <a href="w3c.org">llb</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: The buttons are inside an `<aside>`, which is a block-level element, so it fills the full width.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Thank you! Is there any post online to read in order to understand this weird effect? I would like to have an in-dept understanding about it.

Comment: I would start with the link to the Block Level elements I added in the solution. Getting familiar with Block Level and Inline elements will be really helpful in understanding how elements are formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<button>`s are inside an `<aside>`, which is a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements).

> Browsers typically display the block-level element with a newline both before and after the element. You can visualize them as a stack of boxes.

Add a style to make the `<aside>` a `display: inline-block;` (or `float: left;`) to achieve the effect you want.

```css
aside {
    padding: 0.4rem; 
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0.25rem;
}

.anchor {
    display: block;
    /*width: 30vw;*/
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(22, 122, 56);
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/" class="anchor">Wiki</a>
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/" class="anchor">Impeach</a>
</aside>
<a href="w3c.org">llb</a>

<div></div>

<aside class="inline-block">
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/" class="anchor">Wiki</a>
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/" class="anchor">Impeach</a>
</aside>
<a href="w3c.org">llb</a>
```